# Google Apps Script permissions reset regularly

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that uses `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. It works fine when I run it in the editor and when I schedule it to run daily, I grant permissions and it runs fine a couple times but then I'll get "Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch". I re-save the trigger, regrant permissions, and it runs fine a couple more days. Then the cycle repeats.

How can I extend the amount of time permissions are granted for?

Comment: Have you tried [explicitly setting up the scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) for `UrlFetchApp.fetch` *(*[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external\_request](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request)*)* in your Google Apps Script project?